# Does each pub/sub topics require its own connection GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We start using pub/sub for tracking data. On pub sub we have 600+ topics.

Our developer said that each topics require dedicated connection to GCP thus application require additional file descriptors equal to number of topics. Is this correct? I cannot find any pub/sub documentation mentioning this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "connection to GCP." If you are using the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), then you will need to instantiate a publisher client for each topic.